# Spark can not load the csv file

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("spark://ip:7077") \
.appName("usres mobile location information analysis") \
.config("spark.submit.deployMode", "client") \
.config("spark.executor.memory","2g") \
.config('spark.executor.cores', "2") \
.config("spark.executor.extraClassPath","/opt/anaconda3/jars/ojdbc6.jar") \
.config("spark.executor.pyspark.memory","2g") \
.config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "2g") \
.config("spark.driver.memory", "2g") \
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","/opt/anaconda3/jars/ojdbc6.jar") \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()
```

I am trying to read a csv file located in my local pc in report folder.But it is not located in the masted location. Is there any problem with my code. I use the following line code to read the csv file.

```
info_df = spark.read\
.format("csv")\
.option("header","true")\
.option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")\
.load("report/info.csv")
```

And I get the following error. It is showing the spark can't find the files.What is the probable solution ?

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o580.load.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 31, ip , executor 4): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/C:/Users/taimur.islam/Desktop/banglalink/Data Science/High Value Prediction/report/info.csv does not exist
    It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

Comment: report/info.csv must exist in every executor node.

Comment: my master node is linux, and local pc is windows. How can i configure same path ?? what will be the location of the file in master node?

Comment: You should either use a distributed file system (such as gcp blob, aws s3 ) or homogeneous cluster with copy of the input on each node on the same path.

Comment: Or you can run you client in vm which is linux.

Comment: can you give me some link about the implementation of homogenous cluster system

Comment: homogenous cluster system which means both your client  and spark cluster are  linux ~:D

Comment: are you running spark-submit on windows ?

Comment: @Amit No, why should i need spark-submit ??

Comment: I meant how do you run this application ?